# Loop through two columns on one sheet, find corresponding unique row on another sheet, and return value in third column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, criteria

I have columns A and B in a sheet ("Reference") which contain certain criteria. I want my macro to loop through these criteria, look through columns A and B in another sheet ("Pages"), find the unique corresponding row, and return the value in the third column of that sheet if it's not blank.

Below is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't return any value:

```
    For Each i In sheetrng
       For Each j In proprng

         Dim x As Long, LR As Long, Flag As Boolean
         LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         For x = 3 To LR
             If Range("A" & x) = "Theo Caliber" And Range("B" & x) = i And Range("C" & x) = j And Not IsEmpty(Range("D" & x)) Then
                 Flag = True
                 Exit For
             End If
         Next x

         Dim y As Integer
         y = Rows(2).Find(what:="Total Marketing", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Column

         Dim z As Variant
         Set z = Cells(x, y)


         ThisWorkbook.Activate
         Sheets("Total Rated").Range("B67").Value = 6
         Sheets("Total Rated").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
         FileName:="C:\Users\mercolani\Desktop\2015\By Department\" & z & ".pdf", _
         OpenAfterPublish:=False

       Next j
    Next i
```

Any good soul out there that knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just use a `VLOOKUP` with a compound key.

Comment: You have a lot of `Range()` in there which do not have a specific sheet qualifier: without that they will by default refer to the active sheet, and that may not always be what you want.  It's tricky to tell what really going on in your code since there's some amount of context missing.

Comment: @TimWilliams I activate the relevant sheet just before, so that shouldn't be the issue. Following jbarker's advice, I have reduced the criteria to 1 column. However, I have noticed that the issue lies with the piece of code that loops for x: it returns the first entirely blank row, instead of the one that answers to my criteria. Do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: `Range("A" & x) = "Theo Caliber"` should never be satisfied by a blank row, so there's some other issue there.

Comment: @TimWilliams I figured it out, thanks anyways